# Need help comparing two dates with times

Tags: xslt, data-view-web-part, date-time

I'm trying to compare two dates with time. I'm able to compare just the date, but when I add the time element it doesn't work. I'm not sure what the correct format should be.

```
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:TodayIso(),1033,'yyyyMMdd hhmmss') &lt; ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Date_x002f_Time), 1033, 'yyyyMMdd hhmmss')">
            Test
            </xsl:if>
```

My goal is to compare the two dates to check if there is less than 30 minutes to the Date_x002f_Time field. If it is 3:30pm today and @Date_x002f_Time value is 3:35pm then my value will not show. If it is 3:00pm today and Date_x002f_Time value is 3:35pm then my value will show

Answer (score 0):

Try to define two variables for `data1` and `date2` as the following

```
<xsl:variable name="date1" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTimeUsingCurrentContext(string(@First-date))"/>

<xsl:variable name="date2" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTimeUsingCurrentContext(string(@Second-date))"/>
```

then compare as the following

```
<xsl:if test="$date1 &lt;= $date2">

</xsl:if>
```

Comment: check the  condition &lt;= and firld name in variable defination

Comment: I changed to gt and lt and made sure I was using the correct datetime fields. But still no results.